# How to resume playing audio with MediaPlayer?

Tags: wpf, media-player, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF Caliburn.Micro application, and I use MediaPlayer class to play audio. I implemented Play, Stop, and Pause functionality, but I don't see a method for Resume (after Pause) in MediaPlayer. Could you please help me with this?

Here is some of my code:

```
       public void Play()
   {
       try
       {
           var audio = Tpv.GetAudio(SelectedTpv.TpvId);
           var file = Path.GetTempFileName().Replace(".tmp", ".wma");
           File.WriteAllBytes(file, audio);

           Player.Open(new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute));
           Player.Play();
           IsPlaying = true;

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Failed to play audio:\n{0}", ex.Message), "Failure",
            MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

           Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
       }        
   }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `Play` is also supposed to handle resume functionality.  According to the MSDN for [System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer%28v=vs.100%29) the `Play` method is supposed to "Play media from the current Position".  This means that when you are playing media from the beginning, the position is 0.  If you pause, then the media will be paused at a certain position.  Pressing play again should resume playback from the same position that you paused the media on.

**Edit:**

Based on the code update you provided, it looks like your issue is that you are loading the file each time you click play.  This would cause any previous pause information to be erased, and would treat the file as being brand new each time.  You should put some sort of check in there to say that if the file is not already loaded, then load it.  Otherwise, your `Play` method should just call `Player.Play()` to resume.

I would also note that you would need to also call `Player.Close` when you switch the selected item.  This would let the `Play` method know that it needs to load a different file.

```
public void Play()
{
   try
   {
       // Check if the player already has a file loaded, otherwise load it.
       if(Player.Source == null) { 
           var audio = Tpv.GetAudio(SelectedTpv.TpvId);
           var file = Path.GetTempFileName().Replace(".tmp", ".wma");
           File.WriteAllBytes(file, audio);

           Player.Open(new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute));
       }

       Player.Play();
       IsPlaying = true;

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Failed to play audio:\n{0}", ex.Message), "Failure",
        MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }        
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought the same way, but it doesn't work for me. When I press Play, it plays from the beginning. Maybe I am missing some settings?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what type of media files you are playing.  If it's streaming audio, it may not allow resume.  Pausing in this case would be the same as pressing stop.   You'll have to consult the documentation for the audio format you are using, and also debug your code to see what the value of `CanPause` is for your `MediaPlayer` as well as the value of `Position` when you click Pause.

Comment: It is a wma file, and CanPause is true, and Position has a value. And when I play a .wma file in WindowsMediaPlayer, I can stop and resume...

Comment: Could you please update your question and post the code that you are calling when your `Play` button is pressed?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Only MediaPlayer doesn't know Uri, so I use Player.Source instead.